# Normalization issue

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm trying to normalize this relation:

```
film_year  film_name  critic_id critic_name cinemas_debut           score
     2004  I robot          111        John  NY_cinema, LA_cinema       4 
     2004  I robot          222     Mathiew  NY_cinema, LA_cinema       5
```

Where ...

- film_year and film_name identifies a film.
- Cinemas_debut is a multivaluated attribute.
- critic_id -> critic_name
- film_year, film_name, critic_id -> score

I'm not able to transform relation to 3FN. This is that I have tried:

- Step 1

To 1NF:

```
film_year  film_name  critic_id critic_name cinemas_debut           score
     2004  I robot          111        John  NY_cinema                  4 
     2004  I robot          222     Mathiew  LA_cinema                  5
     2004  I robot          111        John  NY_cinema                  4 
     2004  I robot          222     Mathiew  LA_cinema                  5
```

- Step 2

To 2NF:

I identify `critics` relation as  `critics ( critic_id (pk), critic_name )`
Also `reviews` relation as `reviews(film_year (pk), film_name (pk), critic_id (pk), score)` 
But I don't know what to do with resultant relation:

```
film_year  film_name  critic_id cinemas_debut          
     2004  I robot          111    NY_cinema                   
     2004  I robot          222    LA_cinema                  
     2004  I robot          111    NY_cinema                   
     2004  I robot          222    LA_cinema
```

What is wrong in my approach? Can someone translate this relation to 3FN? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the following:

```
create table films
(
  film_id int,
  film_year int,
  film_name varchar(50)
);

create table critics
(
  critic_id int,
  critic_name varchar(50)
);
```

After you create the table for the `films` and `critics` create a join table between the two

```
create table film_critic
(
  film_id int,
  critic_id int,
  score int
);
```

Then to get the locations, create a table for premier cities/locations

```
create table premiere_locations
(
  location_id int,
  location_name varchar(50)
);
```

Finally create a join table between the film and the location cities

```
create table film_location
(
  film_id int,
  location_id int
);
```

Then to query your data you would use:

```
select f.film_year,
  f.film_name,
  c.critic_id,
  c.critic_name,
  fc.score,
  l.location_name
from films f
left join film_critic fc
  on f.film_id = fc.film_id
left join critics c
  on fc.critic_id = c.critic_id
left join film_location fl
  on f.film_id = fl.film_id
left join premiere_locations l
  on fl.location_id = l.location_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4161/1)

Comment: +1. Hi, I know the final design, but I don't know how to get it. I need detailed steps.

Comment: No part of normalization involves adding additional columns of id numbers.

Comment: @Catcall those fields were added so that the values are not repeated in multiple tables.  I don't believe that my version warrants a downvote from you.

Comment: In a question about normalization, adding additional columns of ID numbers is factually incorrect.

Comment: @Catcall well you already downvoted, so feel free to post an alternative answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

I would have modeled differently. Based on the parameters, there would be 3 entities:
- Cinemas (cinemas_debut) >> Note, you must create a primary key (i.e cinemas_id)
- Films (film_year, film_name) >> Note, you must create a primary key (i.e. film_id)
- Critics (critic_id (PK), critic_name, score)

Now, it is a matter of interpretation. In my opinion, the critics are related to 1 film played in one particular cinema. Therefore, I would create an association
- Show(cinemas_id (FK), films_id (FK), critics_id (FK))

This way, you will have:

- Cinemas: 2 records (C1, C2)
- Films: 1 record (F1)
- Critics: 2 critics (CR1, CR2)
- Shows: 2 records (C1-F1-CR1, C2-F1-CR2)

Does it sound better?
Serge

Comment: +1. Hi, I know the final design, but I don't know how to get it. I need detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

- 1St NF - No repeating elements or groups of elements
  You did it: deduplicate cinemas
- 2nd NF: No partial dependencies on a concatenated key
  In other word, ensure there is a value (couple of values) identifying uniquely the other attributes

Critic(critic_id, critic_name, score) (/* I guess the score is part of the critic*/)

Film(film_name, film_year): you could use those 2 fields to identify uniquely the film, but it won't be 3rd NF -> Add a PK film_id
Film(film_id (FK), film_name (FK), film_year (FK))

Cinema (cinema_name): won't be in 3rd NF -> Add a PK cinema_id
Cinema(cinema_id, cinema_name)
Film(film_id, film_name, film_year)

You need to associate a film to a cinema, to a critic. Depending on the context of critic:

- The score depends on the film and the cinema
  Show(cinema_id, film_id, critic_id)
- The score depends only on the film
  Show(film_id, critic_id) where the primary key is the couple of foreign keys (identifies one couple of cinema/film/critic) and is in 3rd normal form (you don't process on of these 3 FK separaterly)
  Film(cinema_id (FK), film_id, film_name, film_year)
- 3rd NF: No Dependencies on Non-Key Attributes
  In other word, be sure that no attribute is identified by a part of a complex key. You don't have any attribute depending on the only complex key of the system (cinema_id/film_id/critic_id in show in alternative 1 only)

Sounds clear?
Serge