# Step by Step normalization from 1NF to 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm trying to normalize this relation:

```
film_year  film_name  critic_id critic_name cinemas_debut           score
     2004  I robot          111        John  NY_cinema, LA_cinema       4 
     2004  I robot          222     Mathiew  NY_cinema, LA_cinema       5
```

Where ...

- film_year and film_name identifies a film.
- Cinemas_debut is a multivaluated attribute.
- critic_id -> critic_name
- film_year, film_name, critic_id -> score

I'm not able to transform relation to 3FN. This is that I have tried:

- Step 1

To 1NF: No repeating elements or groups of elements:

```
film_year  film_name  critic_id critic_name cinemas_debut           score
     2004  I robot          111        John  NY_cinema                  4 
     2004  I robot          222     Mathiew  LA_cinema                  5
     2004  I robot          111        John  NY_cinema                  4 
     2004  I robot          222     Mathiew  LA_cinema                  5
```

- Step 2

To 2NF: No partial dependencies on a concatenated key: I take as PK `film_year, film_name, critic_id, cinemas_debut`. Then `critic_name` and `score` ara partial dependents, I take out of relation this attributes with a copy of their determinant:

```
 critics ( critic_id (pk), critic_name )
 reviews(film_year (pk), film_name (pk), critic_id (pk), score)
```

But I don't know what to do with resultant relation:

```
film_year  film_name  critic_id cinemas_debut          
     2004  I robot          111    NY_cinema                   
     2004  I robot          222    LA_cinema                  
     2004  I robot          111    NY_cinema                   
     2004  I robot          222    LA_cinema
```

At this time I don't know how to apply normalization to this resultant relation. That I looking for is a **step by step normalization**. I don't need the final result. I wan't to learn normalization rules because this I need step by step table normalization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Normalization issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685177/normalization-issue)

Answer (score 1):

This would be your 3NF, however I have not tested the constraints.

```
film (name, year) 
PK > (name, year)

critic (id, name) 
PK > id

film_critic (film_name, film_year, critic_id, score) 
PK > (film_name, film_year, critic_id)
FK > (film_name, film_year) & critic_id

cinema (name)
PK > name

film_cinema (film_name, film_year, cinema_name)
PK > (film_name, film_year, cinema_name)
FK > (film_name, film_year) & cinema_name
```

It would be easier to use a surrogate key instead of referencing the film name and year (for cinema as well).

```
film (id, name, year)
PK > id

critic (id, name)
PK > id

film_critic (film_id, critic_id, score)
PK > (film_id, critic_id)
FK > film_id & critic_id

cinema (id, name)
PK > id

film_cinema (film_id, cinema_id)
PK > (film_id, cinema_id)
FK > film_id & cinema_id
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't want to vote down, but I looking for step by step normalization but final solution. Please, post step by step or delete answer to avoid me to vote down!! Thanks!!!